# how to get CDATA in xml file using tinyxml library. If possible give a 2-3 line code snippet?

Tags: xml, tinyxml

how to get CDATA in xml file using tinyxml library. If possible give a 2-3 line code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

TinyXML sees CDATA as text:

http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlText.html

It should be a TxXmlText node where the CDATA() method returns true.

Minor point of caution: there isn't a test case for this the TinyXML test suite (xmltest.cpp).